# How to use mutate to define a new variable based on "if, then" conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

For example, say I had a simple dataset like this:

```
  student numerical_score
1     tom            84.7
2   betty            77.3
3    jose            91.5
```

and I wanted to use mutate from dplyr to create an additional variable called "letter_grade" that assigns a later grade based on the value from "numerical_score". For example, tom would have a B, Betty a C+, and Jose an A-. I'm able to use mutate to create a variable based on a single condition, but I'm not sure how to do it here. Any tips on how to write that code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut`/`findInterval` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(letter_grade = cut(numerical_score, c(0, 40, 60, 80, 90, 95, 100), 
                            c('F', 'D', 'C+', 'B', 'A-', 'A+')))
df

#  student numerical_score letter_grade
#1     tom            84.7            B
#2   betty            77.3           C+
#3    jose            91.5           A-
```

Here, we assign grade between 0-40 as `'F'`, 40-60 as `'D'`, 60-80 as `'C+'` and so on. You can change the breaks and `labels` as per your exact values.

---

Another option is to assign each grade individually based on condition in `case_when` -

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(letter_grade = case_when(numerical_score > 95 ~ 'A+', 
                                  numerical_score > 90 ~ 'A-', 
                                  numerical_score > 80 ~ 'B', 
                                  numerical_score > 60 ~ 'C+', 
                                  numerical_score > 500 ~ 'D', 
                                  TRUE ~ 'F'))
```